# OpenCV QRCodeDetector causes ValueError too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, opencv, valueerror

Help me, I have a problem about error

```
Camera ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\testtest00\code24-2.py", line 15, in <module>
    text, points = qrCodeDetector.detectAndDecode(image)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

```py
import sys
import cv2
import time
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if (camera.isOpened() == False):
    print("Can not open camera #0.")
    sys.exit(0)
print("Camera ready")
doAgain = True
while doAgain:
    ret, image = camera.read()
    if ret:
        qrCodeDetector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
        text, points = qrCodeDetector.detectAndDecode(image)
        if points is not None:
            print(text)
            cv2.imwrite("./result.jpg",image)
        else:
            print("QR code not detected")
        cv2.imshow("Image", image)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if key == 27: # ESC
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            doAgain = False
camera.release()
```

[image]

Comment: The method is returning more than two values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`qrCodeDetector.detectAndDecode()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/de/dc3/classcv_1_1QRCodeDetector.html#a7290bd6a5d59b14a37979c3a14fbf394) method returns 3 values; `retval`, `points` and `straight_qrcode`.

So simply replace the line

```
text, points = qrCodeDetector.detectAndDecode(image)
```

with

```
text, points, _ = qrCodeDetector.detectAndDecode(image)
```

Comment: @zerozerochan My pleasure!